# GPOs are on users gpresult but not updating settings

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have the GPOs setup correctly for WSUS and even just adding a favorite in IE but none of these are working. Is there another setting somewhere I'm missing to get these things to force? Windows Server 2008 and all clients are Windows 7.

Comment: How have you configured the GPOs?  Linked to an applicable OU containing the users? Or the computers?  Security filtering?  WMI filtering?  What's the resultant set of policy tool say?

Comment: I have configured the GPO's.  Linked them to my OU that all of my domain users are in.  Security filtering just has authenticated users.

Comment: The IE Favorite one was applied but the WSUS settings were not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WSUS policy is not being applied because WSUS policies are computer configuration.  The GPO that contains those settings must be linked to an OU which contains the relevant computer objects.

Comment: GEEZ  I have no idea why the computers are not in GPO

Comment: @Intelwalk Your comment makes no sense. As Shane has explained, your COMPUTER objects need to be in the same OU that has the GPO applied, if you want the computer settings to be applied. You stated in your comment to your question that you applied the policy to your USER OU. Computer settings apply to computer accounts. User settings apply to user accounts. See also [loopback processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287).

Answer (score 2):

On the clients run:

> gpupdate /force /sync /boot

Then on the client run

> gpresult > c:\gpresult.txt

Review the result and confirm if the newly created GPO is correctly being applied. As Shane mentioned, you can also run the resultant set of policy tool from the DC.

Comment: The IE Favorite one was applied but the WSUS settings were not.

Comment: +1 for resultant set of policy from group policy management. This is always my first port of call when diagnosing group policy issues.